# Can I put a 1TB HDD in my optical Bay

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, optical-drive, unibody

I have a 2011 17" MacBook Pro with a 1TB HDD installed and running the latest OSX. I am looking at installing a SSD in the original HD bay for my OS and Programs and moving the 1TB drive to the optical bay. My current HDD location says it has a link speed of 6Gb/s and negotiated link speed of 3Gb/s and the optical drive says it has a link speed of 6Gb/s with a negotiated speed of 1.5Gb/s.

So my question is twofold. First, will my current drive work correctly in the optical drive bay and secondly,  can I install  a 1TB in the optical bay caddy?  Most of the adapters specify up to 500Gb.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes.  You can put a 1TB drive in there.

The port that your optical drive connects to is a standard SATA III port.  This is why you are seeing that it supports 6Gb/s.  The "negotiated" speed is the speed at which the device will communicate.  A SATA I drive has a transfer rate of 1.5Gb/s.  So, even though SATA III can go 6Gb/s, a SATA I can't go any faster.

A [SATA III port is backward compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) with SATA II and SATA I.  That being said, a SATA port is a SATA port - it doesn't care if you are attaching a spinning hard disk, an optical disk or an SSD.  SATA supports [48-bit LBA (Logical Block Addressing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing#LBA48) which means your drive can be up to 128 PB (Peta Bytes) or 128,000 1TB drives.  So, there is no limitation from a hardware standpoint.

I have personally used [this model optical bay drive caddy](http://radnex.us/MacBook_Pro_optical_bay_drive_caddy) with a 1TB drive with no problems.  The specs say "up to 500GB" but I suspect that since this product has been out for such a long time, they just never bothered to update the marketing material.

[image: optical bay drive caddy]

Answer (score -1):

Try [MacSales.com](http://macsales.com) and use My Upgrades.  Note that your year model has three different versions.

1. I did attempt to guess on your specific version. You can find your specific version under About This Mac from the Apple menu.
2. I didn't gleam the specific answers to your questions, however it seems plausible.  I'd call them to confirm before ordering.