# Can I use any hardware on MBP retina late 2012 on a MBP mid 2012 (non retina)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware

My CD drive does not work on MBP 13 mid 2012 and I ended paying over the odds on a late 2012 13” retina which has a screen problem it does not turn on, when connected to external monitor it’s all well. Took it to few technicians and they can’t sort the problem out. I really can’t afford to spend 300 quid on a screen replacement. Any recommendations or guidance will be appreciated, I’m quite new to Mac products so might need some further assistance:)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you come to find this site a useful resource. In the meantime, can you clarify what you're actually asking of us? If I understand your question correctly, you opted to buy a MBP with no optical drive because your other MBP's optical drive doesn't work, so I'm a little confused by this?Then your question explains the MBP you bought has a bad screen. We'd love to help if we can, but it's unclear whether your main requirement is to get the optical drive working on the mid-2012 MBP or to get the screen working on the late-2012 MBP that has no CD drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Displays

As far as your displays go, you aren't going to be able to swap them.  The late 2012 Retina display model uses a 40 pin LVDS connector, while the non-Retina mid 2012 model uses the older 30 pin connector.  I answered a very similar question to this:

[Replace MacBook Pro screen with Screen from old MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351339/replace-macbook-pro-screen-with-screen-from-old-macbook/351347#351347)

If you really must have the Retina display, then you'll need to get a new display.

#### DVD Drive

If your CD/DVD drive doesn't work, is it really necessary to have?  You can remove the DVD and install a [SATA caddy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257116/119271) that can contain a hard drive for data storage and/or backups or another SSD to create a larger (CoreStorage) volume or a RAID volume; mirrored (for redundancy) or striped (for performance)

Comment: Thanks for your insight Allan, could a novel mac user replace the cd drive with a 128gb ssd coming of late 2012 retina? Do I need any other part to change the hardware, enclosure or a connector? Or would it sit properly without additions?

Comment: No.  It's a PCIe SSD, not a SATA.  If there is an adapter out there, you'd have to get the caddy, the adapter, then insert the SSD.  It' would be far easier, cheaper, and more reliable to just get the caddy and a regular SATA SSD.